# Efficient ways to manage GC Pressure while rendering images

Tags: image, performance, winforms, garbage-collection

I'm currently working on a project where I need to render images to the screen.
I have a networking class that exposes an Observable that delivers the images in a Jpeg format `byte[]`.

The way I'm currently doing it is converting the `byte[]` into a Bitmap and calling `Invalidate()` on the form. The image is then painted using `e.Graphics.DrawImageUnscaled` function.

The problem is it may get called anywhere from 20 to 100 times per second and creating a new `Bitmap`/`MemoryStream` and disposing them is ridiculous GC pressure that I'd like to avoid if possible.

What would be some possible solutions to minimize this pressure?

Also, I'm not currently loving GDI and so would like to hear some other options that might increase performance.

Comment: I don't think the human eyes can detect all that per second. So, reduce the `Invalidate();` calls to a reasonable number. Skip some rounds to not create bitmaps unnecessarily.